# Distribution of rainfall over locations per year

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference, random-variable

> $5.2$ Suppose $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ are jointly continuous and independent, each distributed with marginal pdf $f(x)$, where each $X_{i}$ represents annual rainfall at a given location.
>
> (a) Find the distribution of the number of years until the first year's rainfall, $X_{1}$, is exceeded for the first time

I am working through this problem in a statistical inference book but I am unsure how to interpret it. Does each random variable represent a year and the probability space represents each of the different locations? So this would mean that $\omega \in \Omega$ is a location and in the first year it had $X_1(\omega)$ amount of rainfall?

I am thinking that I am looking to find the distribution of the random variable $$\omega \mapsto \min \{i\in \mathbb{N}: X_i(\omega)>X_1(\omega)\}$$

have I interpreted this problem correctly?

Comment: Given the question, it seems to me that the index represents years, and there is only one location.  $\omega$ is really irrelevant to the problem, at least part (a).

Comment: @jbowman Could you give me a hypothetical example of what each $\omega$ could represent? I'm failing to appreciate why the problem might be constructed this way

Comment: What good does it do you to have $\omega$ in the solution at all?  Why not just find the distribution of $\min_i : x_i > x_1$?  Note that there is no $\omega$ in the problem statement, implying that you don't need one in the solution either.

Comment: Also, please add the self-study tag...

Comment: @jbowman Thank you I have taken a stab at it here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579403/statistical-inference-question-evaluating-a-joint-probability-mesure-w-r-t-a-di but i'm really stuck on how exactly to computet the distribution of this discrete r.v.. Is this distribution computed by a conditional expectation?