# Statistical inference question evaluating a joint probability mesure w.r.t. a distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference, random-variable

Note: I have edited this question and delted my old question after following the guidlines to be more clear. I hope this new question is clear and well posed.

I attempted this question but I got stuck understanding the solution I found online

> 5.2 Suppose $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ are jointly continuous and independent, each distributed with marginal pdf $f(x)$, where each $X_{i}$ represents annual rainfall at a given location.
> (a) Find the distribution of the number of years until the first year's rainfall, $X_{1}$, is exceeded for the first time.
>
> (a) Let $N$ denote the number of years until the first year's rainfall, $X_{1}$, is exceeded for the first time. Then, for $n \geq 2$,
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> P(N=n-1) &=\int_{0}^{\infty} P\left(X_{1}=x, X_{2} \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1} \leq x, X_{n}>x \mid X_{1}=x\right) f(x) \mathrm{d} x \\
> &=\int_{0}^{\infty} F^{n-2}(x)(1-F(x)) f(x) \mathrm{d} x \quad(u=F(x)) \\
> &=\int_{0}^{1} u^{n-2}(1-u) \mathrm{d} u \\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)
> \end{aligned}
> $$

Why must we integrate with respect to $x$? More specifically, what is the formal justification for this equality holding

$$P(N=n-1) =\int_{0}^{\infty} P\left(X_{1}=x, X_{2} \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1} \leq x, X_{n}>x \mid X_{1}=x\right) f(x) \mathrm{d} x? \\
$$

My instict for turning the probability of $N=n-1$ into an expectation would be:

$$P(N=n-1)\\
=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\{\omega: X_{1}=x, X_{2} \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1} \leq x, X_{n}>x \}} \right]\\
=\int_\Omega1_{\{\omega: X_{1}(\omega)=x, X_{2}(\omega) \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x \}} dP\omega
$$

but this does not make use of any conditional expectation. How can I arrive at first equality of the solution?

EDIT: Here is my full thought process:

First, observe that $\{N=n-1\}=\left\{\omega \in \Omega: \exists x \in \mathbb{R} X_{1}(\omega)=x, X_{2}(\omega) \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x, \right\}$

Now $$P(N=n-1)\\
=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{N=n-1}\right]\\
=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left\{\omega \in \Omega: \exists x \in \mathbb{R} X_{1}(\omega)=x, X_{2}(\omega) \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x, \right\}}\right]
$$

By the law of total expectation

$$=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left\{\omega \in \Omega: \exists x \in \mathbb{R}X_{1}(\omega)=x, X_{2}(\omega) \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x, \right\}}\mid X_1\right] \right]\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left\{\omega \in \Omega:\exists x \in \mathbb{R} X_{1}(\omega)=x, X_{2}(\omega) \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x, \right\}}\mid X_1 = x \right] f(x)dx\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}\left({\left\{\omega \in \Omega:\exists x \in \mathbb{R} X_{1}(\omega)=x, X_{2}(\omega) \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x, \right\}}\mid X_1 = x \right) f(x)dx\\
$$

Now $$\mathbb{P}\left({\left\{\omega \in \Omega:\exists x \in \mathbb{R} X_{1}(\omega)=x, X_{2}(\omega) \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x, \right\}}\mid X_1 = x \right)\\
=\frac{\mathbb{P}({\left\{\omega \in \Omega:\exists x \in \mathbb{R} X_{1}(\omega)=x, X_{2}(\omega) \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x, \right\}}\cap \{X_1=x\})}{\mathbb{P}(\{X_1=x\})}\\
=\frac{\mathbb{P}({\left\{X_{1}(\omega)=x\}) \mathbb{P}(\{X_{2}(\omega) \leq x\}) \ldots \mathbb{P}(\{X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x\}) \mathbb{P}(\{X_{n}(\omega)>x \right\}})}{\mathbb{P}(\{X_1=x\})}$$

So we have

$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}(\{X_{2}(\omega) \leq x\}) \ldots \mathbb{P}(\{X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x\}) \mathbb{P}(\{X_{n}(\omega)>x \})f(x)dx\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) \ldots F(X) (1-F(X))f(x)dx$$

Comment: Are you asking whether [LOTUS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=LOTUS) holds?  If not, could you elaborate on what you are trying to do?  (Incidentally, the question is more easily addressed with a symmetry argument: it's clear $X_1$ has a $1/n$ chance of being the largest of the first $n$ values and that the event in question is that $X_1$ is the largest of $n-1$ but *not* largest of $n$ values, whence the answer is $1/(n-1)-1/n$--with no integration required!)

Comment: @whuber I'm trying to understand the thought process of that integration solution. Namely how they went from "we need to compute $P(N=n-1)$" to realizing this is equal to conditional probability integrated. I don't understand how they knew to condition on X_1=x, and further that they should have integrated over all the possible values $X_1$ could take on. I would be really grateful if someone could highlight the thinking here.

Comment: Consider how the event is characterized: it is conditional on $X_1.$  That's explicit in the question.

Comment: @whuber ah that makes alot of sense! In my solution what exactly is conditioned? Should I include this conditioning in the expectation writing it instead as $=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\{\omega: X_{1}=x, X_{2} \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1} \leq x, X_{n}>x \}} \mid X_1 = x\right]$ But then where would the integral over all $x$ come into play? I'm used to the theorem which says "if you have a probability of a set this is the same as the integral of the indicator of this set w.r.t. the probability measure". But when conditioning comes into play im not sure what to do .

Comment: Your expectation is for the indicator of the event $\mathcal{A} := X_1 = x; X_2\le x,\ldots, X_{n-1}\le x, X_n\gt x.$ Use the property $\Pr(\mathcal{A})=E[\mathcal{I}(\mathcal A)]=E[E[\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{A})\mid X_1]].$

Comment: @whuber Is $\mathcal{A}$ defined as $\{\omega \in \Omega: X_{1}(\omega)=x ,X_{2} (\omega)\leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\}$? namely for every possible value that  $x$ could take on?

Comment: @whuber This would mean that we consider the event of points from $\Omega$ which for some value rainfall amount $x$, $X_1$ takes on that value and is exceeded at the $n$th year?

Comment: The correct quantifier is *there exists:* $\mathcal A = \{\omega\in\Omega\mid \exists x\ X_1(\omega) = x, X_2(\omega)\le x, \ldots, X_n(\omega)\gt x\}.$

Comment: @whuber ah of course this makes a lot of sense now thank you!

Comment: @whuber One more thing if you dont mind, how does the exists work when applying independence? does each independent set get an exists statement?

Comment: The description of an event doesn't have anything to do with the probability distribution.  An event is a set, pure and simple.

Comment: @whuber Does that mean I can split this up like this and then apply independence? How then do they apply independence to get from line 1 to line 2? $\left\{\omega \in \Omega:\exists x \in \mathbb{R} X_{1}(\omega)=x, X_{2}(\omega) \leq x, \ldots, X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x, X_{n}(\omega)>x, \right\} = \{\omega \in \Omega : \exists x \in \mathbb{R} X_{1}(\omega)=x\} \cap \{ \omega: X_{2}(\omega) \leq x\} \cap \ldots \cap \{\omega: X_{n-1}(\omega) \leq x\} \cap \{ \omega : X_{n}(\omega)>x\}$

Comment: Again: a description of an event has *nothing* to do with the probability measure.